# I want to map my community site guest user fields to person account fields

Tags: person-accounts, experience-builder-page, self-registration

[image]I have setup my community site and self registration for the guest users, now I want to add some additional fields in the registration page and map these fields value to my account fields. I have tried with formula field but it is not taking proper value. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Hello Apurba, can you please share the code you have used so far? This would help others to help you find a solution.

Comment: Hi Jeferson, I did not used any code here, just configuring with declarative tools. Here I havw also attached the picture in my post

Answer (score 0):

This is using the Self-Registration component. It allows you to add fields on a field set specified on **Extra Fields Fields Set Name**, but these are fields on the User object. More info is found in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317218&type=1).

However, I see you want to set fields into **Account**; for that, you may need to either set the values on User initially and then transfer to Account with automation **or** create your own component for Self-Registration (which is quite common).

Comment: Thank you Jeferson.